# Error al usar && en Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, operador

Tengo un formulario HTML donde se llama a una función de Javascript para validar unos campos de fecha y en el detalle siguiente :

```
if (vfecha_ini =='' && vfelimit_seguro =='' )
```

en el momento de la ejecución reviso con inspeccionar y muestra el siguiente error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

porque en la linea de código hace la siguiente conversión:

`````
if (vfecha_ini =='' ````&#038;&#038;´´´´ vfelimit_seguro =='')
`````

pongo un espacio entre cada caracter pues sino el editor pone directamente &&.

Si pongo, por probar, el operado de || funciona correctamente, pero lo que se necesita es saber si las dos variables están vacías.
¿Alguien me puede ayudar?.

CÓDIGO COMPLETO DEL IF:

```
if (vfecha_fin !='' )
   {if (vfecha_ini =='' && vfelimit_seguro =='' )
       {alert('[ERROR_02.A]\n ¡¡ Si fecha inicio inscripción y fecha limite seguros están sin informar !!\n' + 
                       '¡¡ Fecha final No puede estar informada !!');
        document.Actualizar.felimit_seguro.focus()
        return 0;
       }
    }
```

IMAGEN CON EL ERROR:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pregunta, dónde estás poniendo ese script? en algún archivo plano js o html o hablamos de algún CMS que luego guardas y él te pinta eso, porque está encodeando la salida, y por eso es el error

Comment: Esta dentro de una pagina de HTML, en una función de javascript de validación de datos de los input y validación lógica de datos así como de que estén informados con los valores aceptados.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando comillas, de esta manera:

if (vfecha_ini ==" " && vfelimit_seguro ==" " )

Answer (score 0):

En Javascript puedes simplemente evaluar las variables en sí con algo como:

```
if (var1 && var2) ...
```

Veamos un ejemplo, evaluaremos en negativo para respetar tu propósito:

```js
var vfecha_ini = '';
var vfelimit_seguro = '';

if (!(vfecha_ini && vfelimit_seguro)) {
  console.log("vacías");
}
```

Esto te verifica:

- Si están vacías
- Si son `0`
- Si son `null`
- Si son `undefined`
- Si son `NaN` (Not a Number)

Veamos otro ejemplo:

```js
var vfecha_ini = '';
var vfelimit_seguro = '';
var a=null;

if (!(vfecha_ini && vfelimit_seguro && a && noExiste)) {
  console.log("vacías");
}
```

### Edición con `alert()`

```js
var vfecha_ini = '';
var vfelimit_seguro = '';

if (!(vfecha_ini && vfelimit_seguro)) {
   alert('[ERROR_02.A]\n ¡¡ Si fecha inicio inscripción y fecha limite seguros están sin informar !!\n' + 
                   '¡¡ Fecha final No puede estar informada !!');

}
```

En tu contexto, el código final puede quedar así simplemente:

```
if (vfecha_fin)
   {
       if ( !(vfecha_ini  && vfelimit_seguro) )
       {alert('[ERROR_02.A]\n ¡¡ Si fecha inicio inscripción y fecha limite seguros están sin informar !!\n' + 
                       '¡¡ Fecha final No puede estar informada !!');
        document.Actualizar.felimit_seguro.focus()
        return 0;
       }
    }
```

Comment: @Econed no modifiques las respuestas para aclaraciones, usa el área de comentarios en la respuesta. ¿Entonces lo que quieres realmente no es verificar que ambas están vacías?

Comment: SI, quiero verificar si ambas están vacías, en cuyo caso muestro una alerta con el texto explicativo y retornar al formulario. He incluido el código del párrafo donde da el error.

Comment: @Econed pero el código funciona, sólo tienes que adaptarlo tal cual al tu contexto. Revisa la respuesta editada, al final hay una prueba con `alert`. Pulsando en el botón azul podrás verificar que funciona.

Comment: Me da el mismo error, el problema el mismo del principio convierte el && en ´´´´&#038;&#038;´´´´

Comment: @Econed como puedes verificar en el snippet, el código funciona perfectamente. Tu error debe estar en otra parte.

Comment: He vuelto a incluir el pantallazo de inspeccionar, con la linea localizada del error en sombreado amarillo y mas abajo el texto del error que no deja rodar el script.

Comment: @Econed creo que debes revisar tu configuración/entorno Javascript, pues por algún motivo te está interpretando los caracteres como entidades. Revisa por ejemplo si tienes `utf8` establecido en el meta de tu HTML u otra cosa.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105508/discussion-between-econed-and-a-cedano).

Comment: A. Cedano... tengo otra pregunta, que me gustaría pedirte ayuda ya que tienes bastantes conocimientos y nadie me lo sabe resolver...